# What does "no less than" mean?

Tags: idioms

Can you please explain the meaning of `no less than` with examples?

EDIT:

WOW! I really didn't think that my question was so inferior!

Ok, I will try to add some quality like the one [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8118/what-does-i-stand-corrected-mean):

```
When someone says 'no less than' what does it mean?
```

So you can give me some Cambridge Dictionary and Wikipedia links.

Comment: Please check digital/paper dictionaries first, before asking a question here. This question is easily answerable through normal resources. Please read the [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq) for more information about what questions best fit here.

Comment: Try searching for "none other than", if the literal meaning doesn't make sense to you.

Comment: Also, it might help if you have a read of [this meta post](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity) for more help on asking questions

Comment: Hi Matt. I am not satisfied with the answers I've found on the web. English is not my native language, unlike you. There are lots of questions in this site answered with a link to somewhere. Nobody downvotes people for that. Actually you have questions answered like that,too. I'm surprised with your attitude.

Comment: If you are not happy with the answers you've found, please explain in your question (which you can edit and we can reopen) *what you've found* and *why it doesn't help you*.

Comment: Why is this question closed, but not [The meaning of “no more … than”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18196/the-meaning-of-no-more-than)?

Comment: I think many people say something [is no less than](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+is+no+less+than&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) something else when they really mean *is no more than*. Effectively, they mean **simply**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers — I would say that the quality of the question you linked to is far greater than this one. It explains the problems the questioner is having with the phrase so as to allow a good well thought out answer that can't just be Googled. I find this question does not have the same qualities. If I knew what problems bonsvr was having with the phrase then I could answer.

Comment: @Matt Эллен: It's closed as "general reference", rather than "not a real question". Obviously I personally don't find the surface meaning of the expression opaque, but looking at examples in NGrams I'm intrigued that this version (as opposed to *no more than*) seems to have a far higher proportion of usages in religious contexts. I'm also struck by fact that many instances of *either* version could just as easily have used the word "simply". As a set phrase, it does seem to behave a little oddly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers — The question doesn't say what aspect of the phrase is confusing, e.g. religion, hyperbole, etc. There's, just the desire for a definition. It shows no research or clear direction. I have no doubt that a good question about *no less than* is askable. This is not it.

Comment: ELU is nothing if not democratic, and the weight of opinion is clearly with you on this one. I've just done an NGram comparing [no more/less than](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no+more+than%2Cno+less+than&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), and I'm now even more intrigued. It seems *more* was vastly more common in C18, but gave way to *less* in C19 before regaining dominance through C20. It's certainly an unusual distribution, but I don't think I can just edit OP's question to make it ask about things like that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is an adjective. Little - Less - Least. It is the opposite of greater. "How long is that? Hmm, I don't know, but no less than 1 metre, and not longer than 2 metres eighter. Maybe 1,5?"